# Generating framework with NHibernate for Complex reports

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm developing a application with wpf, Fluent NHibernate and MySQL,we need to generate complex reports. Can anyone help me out to find the best framework to implement for report generation at Database level.

I need help, how should my report manager manage the filter criteria and expression creation.
Should i create sql statements and query the data from session ?
Need support for designing framework for the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Criteria/QueryOver is best suited for dynamic query generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search on Google, a best way to implement some framework for querying to database Reports.
I found some thing like DetachedCriteria for complex queries it solves the my problem.

Reference : http://ayende.com/blog/1900/complex-searching-querying-with-nhibernate

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.